# How to style the citation to be surnames only in the pdf?

Tags: latex

My preamble is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{header}
\usepackage[refsection=part,citestyle=authoryear,style=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=biber, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}  
\bibliography{references.bib}
```

and in the references.bib file I have :

```
@article{Alicemann2017,
  author={ {Alice Alicemann} and {Bob Robertstein} },
  title={The Formation of Uranus via outgassing},
  journal={The Astrophysical Journal},
  volume={10000000},
  number={2},
  pages={95},
  url={http://stacks.iop.org/aaaa },
  year={2017},
}
```

In the main text I have  '''\citep[e.g.,][]{Alicemann2017}'''

How can I force it to present it in the final PDF as:
"(e.g., Alicemann and Robertstein, 2017) " instead of "(e.g., Alice Alicemann an Bob Robertstein, 2017)"? I want to see surnames only, without given names.

Comment: Please make a [mre] that is ready for us to copy&paste instead of this non-compilable code fragment which we can't even complete to a compilable document because it relies on local files we don't have access to

Comment: Please note that [tex.SE] is the more appropriate place to ask pure TeX questions, like this one. If you have a question about LaTeX within another program (e.g. plot annotations in Python or MATLAB), Stack Overflow would be appropriate. Vanilla LaTeX should almost invariably go to [tex.SE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your authors is wrong. By wrapping them into an additional layer of parenthesis, you force biblatex to think that the whole name would be the surname

```
@article{Alicemann2017,
  author={ Alice Alicemann and Bob Robertstein },
  title={The Formation of Uranus via outgassing},
  journal={The Astrophysical Journal},
  volume={10000000},
  number={2},
  pages={95},
  url={http://stacks.iop.org/aaaa },
  year={2017},
}
```

[image]

Please also note that with biblatex it is better to use the actual biblatex syntax of `\addbibressource{references.bib}` instead of the bibtex syntax `\bibliography{references}`

Comment: 10x!
I had to change also to : '[refsection=part,citestyle=authoryear,style=apa,natbib=true,backend=biber, maxcitenames=2]'